# how to store processed data from hdfs using mapReduce in mongoDB as output

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I have a mapreduce application which processed the data from HDFS and stores output data in HDFS

but, now i need to store output data in mongodb insted of storing it in to HDFS

can any one let me know how to do it?

Thank you

MAPPER CLASS

```
package com.mapReduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class FMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private String pART;
    private String actual;
    private String fdate;
    public void map(LongWritable ikey, Text ivalue, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String tempString = ivalue.toString();
        String[] data = tempString.split(",");
        pART=data[1];
        try{
            fdate=convertyymmdd(data[0]);
            /**IF ACTUAL IS LAST HEADER
             * actual=data[2];
             * */
            actual=data[data.length-1];
            context.write(new Text(pART), new Text(fdate+","+actual+","+dynamicVariables(data)));
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae){
            System.err.println(ae.getMessage());
        }

    }


    public static String convertyymmdd(String date){

        String dateInString=null;
        String data[] =date.split("/");
        String month=data[0];
        String day=data[1];
        String year=data[2];
        dateInString =year+"/"+month+"/"+day;
        System.out.println(dateInString);   
        return dateInString;
    }

    public static String dynamicVariables(String[] data){
        StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
        boolean isfirst=true; 
    /** IF ACTUAL IS LAST HEADER
     * for(int i=3;i<data.length;i++){ */
        for(int i=2;i<data.length-1;i++){

            if(isfirst){
                str.append(data[i]);
                isfirst=false;
            }
            else
            str.append(","+data[i]);
        }
        return str.toString();
        }

}
```

REDUCER CLASS

```
package com.mapReduce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import com.ihub.bo.ForcastBO;
import com.ihub.service.ForcastService;
public class FReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    private String pART;
    private List<ForcastBO> list = null;
    private List<List<String>> listOfList = null;
    private List<String> vals = null;
    private static List<ForcastBO> forcastBos=new ArrayList<ForcastBO>();

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text _key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pART = _key.toString();
        // process values
        for (Text val : values) {
            String tempString = val.toString();
            String[] data = tempString.split(",");
            ForcastBO fb=new ForcastBO();
            fb.setPart(pART);
            fb.setDate(data[0]);
            fb.setActual(data[1]);
            fb.setW0(data[2]);
            fb.setW1(data[3]);
            fb.setW2(data[4]);
            fb.setW3(data[5]);
            fb.setW4(data[6]);
            fb.setW5(data[7]);
            fb.setW6(data[8]);
            fb.setW7(data[9]);
            try {
                list.add(fb);
            } catch (Exception ae) {
                System.out.println(ae.getStackTrace() + "****" + ae.getMessage() + "*****" + ae.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);
        try {
          while (context.nextKey()) {

         listOfList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
         list=new ArrayList<ForcastBO>();
            reduce(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getValues(), context);
            files_WE(listOfList, list, context);

          }

          }finally {
              cleanup(context);
            }
    }


    public void files_WE(List<List<String>> listOfList, List<ForcastBO> list, Context context) {

        Collections.sort(list);

            try {
                setData(listOfList, list);

                Collections.sort(listOfList, new Comparator<List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
                        return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
                    }
                });

                for (int i = listOfList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                    List<String> list1 = listOfList.get(i);
                    int k = 1;
                    for (int j = 3; j < list1.size(); j++) {
                        try {
                            list1.set(j, listOfList.get(i - k).get(j));
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            list1.set(j, null);
                        }
                        k++;
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }

            for(List<String> ls:listOfList){
                System.out.println(ls.get(0));
                ForcastBO forcastBO=new ForcastBO();
                try{
                    forcastBO.setPart(ls.get(0));
                    forcastBO.setDate(ls.get(1));
                    forcastBO.setActual(ls.get(2));
                    forcastBO.setW0(ls.get(3));
                    forcastBO.setW1(ls.get(4));
                    forcastBO.setW2(ls.get(5));
                    forcastBO.setW3(ls.get(6));
                    forcastBO.setW4(ls.get(7));
                    forcastBO.setW5(ls.get(8));
                    forcastBO.setW6(ls.get(9));
                    forcastBO.setW7(ls.get(10));
                    forcastBos.add(forcastBO);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        forcastBos.add(forcastBO);
                    }
                try{
                    System.out.println(forcastBO);
                    //service.setForcastBOs(forcastBos);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("FB::::"+e.getStackTrace());
            }
            }
    }





        public void setData(List<List<String>> listOfList, List<ForcastBO> list) {
            List<List<String>> temListOfList=new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            for (ForcastBO str : list) {
                vals = new ArrayList<String>();
                vals.add(str.getPart());
                vals.add(str.getDate());
                vals.add(str.getActual());
                vals.add(str.getW0());
                vals.add(str.getW1());
                vals.add(str.getW2());
                vals.add(str.getW3());
                vals.add(str.getW4());
                vals.add(str.getW5());
                vals.add(str.getW6());
                vals.add(str.getW7());
                temListOfList.add(vals);
            }


            Collections.sort(temListOfList, new Comparator<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
                    return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
                }
            });

            for(List<String> ls:temListOfList){
                System.out.println(ls);
                listOfList.add(ls);
                }
        }

        public static List<ForcastBO> getForcastBos() {
            return forcastBos;
        }



    }
```

DRIVER CLASS

```
package com.mapReduce;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class MRDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "JobName");
        job.setJarByClass(MRDriver.class);
        // TODO: specify a mapper
        job.setMapperClass(FMapper.class);
        // TODO: specify a reducer
        job.setReducerClass(FReducer.class);

        // TODO: specify output types
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        // TODO: delete temp file
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000"),
                conf); 
        Path workingDir=hdfs.getWorkingDirectory();

        Path newFolderPath= new Path("/sd1");
        newFolderPath=Path.mergePaths(workingDir, newFolderPath);
        if(hdfs.exists(newFolderPath))

        {
            hdfs.delete(newFolderPath); //Delete existing Directory

        }
        // TODO: specify input and output DIRECTORIES (not files)

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/Forcast/SampleData"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, newFolderPath);

        if (!job.waitForCompletion(true))
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: FIrst you need code to "read" from HDFS and then you need a MongoDB driver and code your "write" to MongoDB, or just output directly to MongoDB from your "reducer" or final stage as required. Basically get a driver for your language ( hadoop does support a couple in different modes, but maybe you mean Java ), then connect and write,. Learn the driver first though.

Comment: What format is your processed data? You can always call the MongoDB client within the reducer and bulk write the data in the cleanup part (for instance). Please provide more specifics if you are expecting us to help.

Comment: the processed data is in LIST formate

Comment: if required i can add the code

Comment: from the above mapreduce im storing data in hdfs but now i need data in mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is to change the "output format class",and you have several ways there:

1. Use **MongoDB Connector for Hadoop**: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/?_ga=1.111209414.370990604.1441913822
2. Implement your own **OutputFormat**: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputFormat.html (Instead to use FileOutputFormat).
3. Execute **mongodb queries inside the reducer** instead to write in the MapREduce context (Not Nice, you could end with empty outut files in HDFS depending on the OutputFormat specified in the driver)

In my opinion option 1 is the best option but I haven't used MongoDB connector to say if it is enough stable and functional. Option 2 require that you really understand how is working hadoop underhood to avoid end with a lot of open connections and problems with transactions and hadoop tasks retries.

Comment: Rojo do you know how to store output data in a object instead of  storing it into file system

Comment: Could you elaborate your question?  And if is a different question than the original, Could you create a new question to let others with the same problem find it easier?  I will try to help you if I know the answer