# Fastest way to sync (or keep import) 3.5TB data from hadoop to sharded mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, import, hdfs, data-import

There are 3.5TB data in our hadoop cluster(yes on hdfs). And we have newly built a sharded mongodb cluster(the latest 3.x) with 3 mongos, 3 configdb and 3 shards(each shard has 1 primary and 2 secondary nodes)

We are looking for the best/fastest way to import these data from hadoop/hdfs to our newly built sharded mongodb cluster.

All these data will be into sharded collections in mongodb cluster.

We don't have much experience on this and no clue how to do this with the fastest way in our environment.

Appreciate if anyone can give a clue or the tools we can leverage. open source tools or commercial are both ok to us.

Joe

Comment: look into this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500080/how-to-store-processed-data-from-hdfs-using-mapreduce-in-mongodb-as-output/32510591#32510591.

Comment: Thanks Rojo, I will check it out.